# CSRF verification failed, 'CSRF token missing or incorrect'

Tags: django, django-forms

This has been asked many times before and I have read all of those answers, but none of them worked for me so I'd like to try again.

When I try to submit a Django form with username and password, I get this error message:
'CSRF token missing or incorrect'.

The CSRF token is not missing.
Here is where I included it in my form in my .html template:

In **index.html:**

```
<form name="loginform" action="/notes/index/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
    {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
        {{ errors }}
   {% endfor %}
</form>
```

In **views.py:**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

def index(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
     print("Received POST")
     form = LoginForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        print("FORM is Valid")
     else:
        print("FORM is NOT VALID")
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
       'username': 'Benny',
       'form': LoginForm(),
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I also have csrf middleware in settings. I am trying to avoid using @csrf_exempt as this app will go into production down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work but not sure why this fixes it. Can anyone clarify?
I changed:

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

to:

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
```

I thought the request was automatically carried out by render()? So I'm not sure why I had to add `request=request`.